# Python - Figuring out the Xpaths of attribute data-* in HTML

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xpath

Trying to figure out how to extract the data from this webpage and place it into a .csv. file: https://www.basketball-reference.com/draft/BAA_1947.html

The table structure for each row looks something like the following picture below:

```
<tr data-row="12">
    <th scope="row" class="right " data-stat="ranker" >11</th>
        <td class="left " data-stat="player" csk="Bolyard,Robert" >Robert Bolyard</td>
        <td class="left " data-stat="college_name" csk="University of Toledo" ><a href="/friv/draft.fcgi?college=toledo">University of Toledo</a></td>
        <td class="right " data-stat="seasons" >12</td>
</tr>
```

I want to know the Xpath values to grab the text.

So far I have the following:

```
# Xpath
player = data.xpath("//td/span[@data-stat='player']/text()") 
college = data.xpath("//td/span[@data-stat='college_name']/a/text()") 
seasons = data.xpath("//td/span[@data-stat='seasons']/text()")
```

Issue is it doesn't return any values into any column. What might be wrong with the Xpath statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a `span` inside of the `td`, but there isn't one.

If you remove that part of the xpath it will work:

```
player = data.xpath("//td[@data-stat='player']/text()") 
college = data.xpath("//td[@data-stat='college_name']/a/text()") 
seasons = data.xpath("//td[@data-stat='seasons']/text()")
```

Comment: Thank you! This code works as intended. May I ask why the [@data-*=value] is after td?

Comment: The data attribute belongs to the td. So //td[@attr] means find a td, that is a grandchild element, with the attribute 'attr'